# How to call inline magnific-popup via javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I want to call a inlin popup via js function. but how ? i try alot

its working with "type:ajax" but not with "type:inline"

```
    function abc()
    {
     $.magnificPopup.open({items: 
{

src: PAGE_URL,
type: 'ajax'},

closeOnContentClick: false, closeOnBgClick: false, showCloseBtn: true, enableEscapeKey: false,
                                                         });
    }
```

i want same thing for inline popup

eg

```
function xyz()
{
$('.simple-popup').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline'
    });
}
```

Thanks

Comment: ajax and inline are not related in any way at all.

Comment: i know , we can call any page using ajax on function click . 

i want same thing for Inline.

Comment: You have to provide content (e.g. items) for inline popup.

Comment: yes , eg src: 'html code here ', but its not good. i have 100+ line with form and js code. thats why i want to call div block. other wise i need use ajax (thats  means i need to create more and more code for that )